# Xamarin Forms : How to save a file to storage

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to save a downloaded file to my local storage (or SD card) with Xamarin Forms (portable project). I've tried to use PCLStorage, but it is not working (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076456/xamarin-forms-pclstorage-createfileasync-not-found-in-type-pclstorage-ifolder)

Is there another solution to save files? If I can save files too SQLite or something, it is also fine, but I haven't found it yet..

Thanks.

BR,
FG

Comment: have you read the docs?  They give a fairly complete example of doing this.  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/#Saving_and_Loading_Files

Comment: Please also have a look at this 3rd part plugin: https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk I tried to use this 3rd part plugin, but its not working (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076456/xamarin-forms-pclstorage-createfileasync-not-found-in-type-pclstorage-ifolder)

Comment: @Jason I thought a 3rd part plugin was required to use this solution, but I tried to use it in a seperate solution and I can save the files now, thanks. Now I need to figure out how to open the files..